# htaccess - rewrite rule to hide details in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the current rule I want to modify:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} m.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m(.*)$ articles.php?$1
```

The result is:

```
http://www.mywebsite001.com/m/45/Details-I-Want-To-Hide/
```

I would like to get this result:

```
http://www.mywebsite001.com/m/45/
```

(ending by a slash)

Comment: Not really because then, it will interfere with my xml bot submission file. I tried actually to do it without interfering but I could not succeed. That is why I try via the RewriteRule.

Comment: It does not relate to the question, it was just an answer to your comment explaining why I did not do it the way you suggested.